# Link to VCS root in email template in TeamCity

Tags: email, version-control, teamcity

I'm editing my email FTL templates for teamcity. I'd like to know if there's a way to add a link to the repository that the build in the email is connected to. I know that emails in TC are based off of certain builds and not projects, but I'd like to know if there's a way to add the email link to the VCS root of the project that the build is in.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can do it . teamcity exposes the vcs root through teamcity properties

Please checkout [This page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Roots) and [this page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-VCSProperties)to get the exact vcs id that you need. The vcs id will differ based on which type of vcs you use (git, cvs,svn ) etc